# How to store geofence in disk? (android)

Tags: java, android, gson, geofencing, android-geofence

I'm having a problem figuring out a way to store the geofences that my app creates, in order to load them when I run the app again. The purpose is to show a list of geofences created by the user.
I tried to serialize them using Java's Serialization and I also tried to use Gson to convert them into a Json string. The problem with Gson it's when I try to load them, it gives me an error message saying that Geofence is not a class. (which is true, it's an interface).

Thank you in advance.

PS: Here some code from my class

```
public class Manager implements ResultCallback<Status>, LocationListener {

// Tag para fazer debug
protected static final String MAN = "Manager";
protected static final String SMS = "eventSMS";
protected static final String RING = "eventRing";

private Context mAppContext;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

// Listas de Geofences

private TreeMap<String, Geofence> mGeofences;
private TreeMap<String, Event> mEvents;
private int mCounterActiveGeofences;

private PendingIntent mGeofencePendingIntent;

private Intent updateLocIntent;

/* Save  */
private Gson gson;
private SharedPreferences prefs;

public Manager(Context context, GoogleApiClient googleApiClient){

    mGeofences = new TreeMap<String, Geofence>();
    mEvents = new TreeMap<String, Event>();
    mGeofencePendingIntent = null;
    mAppContext = context;
    mGoogleApiClient = googleApiClient;
    mCounterActiveGeofences = 0;
    prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.Geofences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    gson = new Gson();
}

...

public void saveGeofences(){
    String json;
    Geofence geofence;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    Log.d(MAN, "Saving Geofences...");
    for (Map.Entry<String, Geofence> entry : mGeofences.entrySet()) {
        geofence = mGeofences.get(entry.getKey());
        json = gson.toJson(geofence);
        editor.putString(geofence.getRequestId(), json);
        Log.d(MAN, geofence.getRequestId() + " json: " + json);
    }
    editor.apply();
}

public void loadGeofences(){
    Map<String, ?> keys = prefs.getAll();
    Log.d(MAN, "Loading Geofences...");
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : keys.entrySet()) {
        String jsonString = prefs.getString(entry.getKey(), null);
        Geofence geofence = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Geofence.class);
        Log.d(MAN, geofence.getRequestId());
        mGeofences.put(geofence.getRequestId(), geofence);
    }
}
}
```

Here is the LogCat:

```
09-09 21:37:16.148  18137-18137/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
09-09 21:37:17.515  18137-18137/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
09-09 21:37:17.515  18137-18137/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 614: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
09-09 21:37:17.515  18137-18137/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
09-09 21:37:17.515  18137-18137/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
09-09 21:37:17.515  18137-18137/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 636: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
09-09 21:37:17.515  18137-18137/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
09-09 21:37:18.133  18137-18137/? D/GoogleAPIMsg﹕ Construcao do Client Google
09-09 21:37:18.164  18137-18137/? D/Manager﹕ Loading Geofences...
09-09 21:37:18.203  18137-18137/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-09 21:37:18.203  18137-18137/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419307c0)
09-09 21:37:18.234  18137-18137/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.smartlocation.wilcocsjrxxlxpto/com.smartlocation.wilcocsjrxxlxpto.HomeScreen}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence. Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1269)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence. Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
            at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$12.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:210)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:186)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:724)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:696)
            at com.smartlocation.wilcocsjrxxlxpto.core.Manager.loadGeofences(Manager.java:203)
            at com.smartlocation.wilcocsjrxxlxpto.HomeScreen.load(HomeScreen.java:252)
            at com.smartlocation.wilcocsjrxxlxpto.HomeScreen.onCreate(HomeScreen.java:66)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2293)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1269)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.google.gson.internal.UnsafeAllocator$1.newInstance(UnsafeAllocator.java:48)
            at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$12.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:207)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:186)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:724)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:696)
            at com.smartlocation.wilcocsjrxxlxpto.core.Manager.loadGeofences(Manager.java:203)
            at com.smartlocation.wilcocsjrxxlxpto.HomeScreen.load(HomeScreen.java:252)
            at com.smartlocation.wilcocsjrxxlxpto.HomeScreen.onCreate(HomeScreen.java:66)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2293)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1269)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence; abstract class or interface
            at sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.google.gson.internal.UnsafeAllocator$1.newInstance(UnsafeAllocator.java:48)
            at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$12.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:207)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:186)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:724)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:696)
            at com.smartlocation.wilcocsjrxxlxpto.core.Manager.loadGeofences(Manager.java:203)
            at com.smartlocation.wilcocsjrxxlxpto.HomeScreen.load(HomeScreen.java:252)
            at com.smartlocation.wilcocsjrxxlxpto.HomeScreen.onCreate(HomeScreen.java:66)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2293)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1269)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-09 21:37:18.648  18137-18137/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 18137 SIG: 9
```

The line Manager.java:203 is "Geofence geofence = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Geofence.class);" from the class.

The json string generated by trying to serialize a geofence is:

```
Json: {"zzDK":"xxd","zzCY":1,"zzazj":-1,"zzaxB":39.2079714,"zzaxC":-8.9593288,"zzaxD":100.0,"zzaxE":0,"zzaxF":-1,"zzaxy":3,"zzaxA":1}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `android.location.Geofence` instead of `com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence` ?

Comment: Why do you want to store Geofence?

Comment: Can you [edit] to include what a serialized Geofence looks like? Then let me know that you've done so with a comment.

Comment: @durron597: I edited the question with what I think is what you asked.

Comment: @akodiakson : I can try to change to what you are saying, what would be the advantage?

Comment: @MarianPaździoch: Because I need to register them again on device boot, and I want them to appear in the UI so that the user could control them, even if the app is closed.

Comment: @XXLXPTO I was curious because the gms version does not have accessors to make use of the values if you were to retrieve it from storage. It looks like those key values are obfuscations that correspond to the `Geofence.Builder` args.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it directly. You have to mirror your geofence settings (lat, lng, radius, etc.) on your own.